# How to call a method that expects a subclass object with an subclass object referenced by a pointer to its superclass?

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism

I have an object that is referenced by a pointer to its superclass: `Base* d1 = new Derived();`

I would like to pass it to another method that expects an object of the derived class: `void f(Derived* d);`

But it doesn't work unless I use type-casting. Is there another way to achieve this?

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio>
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

class Client
{
   public:
   void f(Base* b) { printf("base"); };
   void f(Derived* d) { printf("derived"); };
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   Client*  c  = new Client();
   Base*    b  = new Base();
   Base*    d1 = new Derived();
   Derived* d2 = (Derived*) d1;

   c->f(b);  // prints "base". Ok.
   c->f(d1); // prints "base"! I expected it to be "derived"!
   c->f(d2); // prints "derived". Type-casting is the only way?
}
```

Comment: You could add a virtual function to Base called call_f, which would call f using the 'this' pointer in base, then override it in the Derived to do the same thing. Either that or CRTP

Comment: This is hard to answer as it stands.  What is the problem you are trying to solve?  Are you bothered about a dynamic_cast<Derived>?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe He is saying he doesn't want to have to resort to casting and if there is a way to do without it.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe That's what I would assume. He has some function which takes a pointer to Derived and he wants to call it but he has a Base pointer. My suggestion of moving the call into a member function of Base/Derived would avoid casts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can do some stuff with *dynamic_cast*.

From the other side I believe, that *dynamic_cast* can practically always be avoided by the good design.

In your example you can make function *f* virtual member of *Base* class and override it in the *Derived* class. Then call it *f* via pointer to *Base*.

Something like this:

```
class Base {
    public:
        virtual void f() {
            printf("Base\n");
        }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        virtual void f() {
            printf("Derived\n");
        }
};

class Client
{
   public:
       void f(Base* b) {
           b->f();
       };
};
```